# How to check whether certain tables are empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I check whether certain datatables (e.g. "tableA", "tableB" & "tableC") are empty in one query (SQL Server)?

**Expected result:**
The most important for me is to have ONE result.

- It could be *true* (if all tables are empty) vs *false*.
- Another possibility is the sum of all entries over all tables like *0* (if all tables are empty) or otherwise *n*.

**Example**

There are three tables in database: table1, table2 and table3.

1. All tables are empty. --> Expected result: **0**
2. Table1 has 3 rows, table2 has 0 rows, table3 has 1 row. --> Expected result: **4**.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can use this DMV which will query the Count from CACHE only..

```
SELECT  SUM(row_count) AS rows
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
where object_name(object_id) in ('table1','tab1e2')
group by OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
```

**Update as per question:**

```
;with cte
as
(SELECT  SUM(row_count) AS rows
        FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
        where object_name(object_id) in ('table1','tab1e2')
        group by OBJECT_NAME(object_id))
select sum(rows) as rows from cte
```

Comment: This one is nearly the expected result. In the end I would like to have the sum of the 'rows' column.

Comment: Not exactly... this one returns as many rows as tables saying how many rows every table has. I'd like to have the sum of all tables in a single row result.

Comment: please update your question with some sample data and expected result.

Comment: OK, I just added a detailed example. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the counts from the tables using `union all`:

```
select 'a', count(*) from a union all
select 'b', count(*) from b union all
select 'c', count(*) from c;
```

However, the fastest way is to use `exists`:

```
select (case when not exists (select 1 from a) then 1 else 0 end) as a_is_empty,
       (case when not exists (select 1 from b) then 1 else 0 end) as b_is_empty,
       (case when not exists (select 1 from c) then 1 else 0 end) as c_is_empty
```

EDIT:

If you want the total rows in the three tables, just add them up:

```
select sum(cnt)
from (select 'a', count(*) as cnt from a union all
      select 'b', count(*) from b union all
      select 'c', count(*) from c
     ) abc;
```

I would be wary about using system tables for this operation, if you need exact, up-to-date results.  System tables are great in a static environment, where the tables aren't changing, but I suspect your environment is more dynamic.

Comment: Maybe it would be faster to use `select top 1 1 from a`

Comment: @psur . . . That shouldn't make a difference.  The `exists` should automatically stop at the first record.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: this is not exactly what I need. Please see my edited question - I described the expected results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

hope below query help you.

```
SELECT
        SCHEMA_NAME(SOS.SCHEMA_ID) + '.' + (SOS.NAME) AS [Table Name]
      , (SPS.Rows) AS [Row Count]
      , [Heap / Clustered Table] = CASE SPS.INDEX_ID WHEN 0 THEN 'HEAP' ELSE 'CLUSTERED' END
FROM 
      sys.objects AS SOS
      INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS SPS
            ON SOS.object_id = SPS.object_id
WHERE
      SOS.type = 'U'
      AND SPS.index_id < 2
      and SPS.Rows =0
ORDER BY [Table Name]
```

Please Mark me as answer if my post helps you.
Regards
ChetanV